# ¿como podría ingresar 5 notas de 5 alumnos y sacar promedio? solo pude hacerlo con 1 alumno

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);

        float notas ;
        float suma = 0;
        float promedio;
        int a;


        for(a=1;a<=5;a++)

        {  
          System.out.println("ingresa la nota:"+a+"");
          notas=leer.nextFloat();
          suma=suma+notas;


        } 


        promedio=suma/(a-1);
        System.out.println("el promedio de las notas es:"+promedio);


        if (promedio >= 5.0)
            System.out.println("El alumno esta aprobado:");

        else
            System.out.println("El alumno esta reprobado:");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Debes crear una matriz de 5x5, la cual debes recorres con un ciclo anidado.

Comment: Para cosas así, te recomiendo que las hagas en papel primero :) Es decir, que hagas el flujo de datos, algo de pseudo código con tal que tenga lógica, todo bien

Comment: Yo pienso que el problema es que guardas las notas en una única variable y lo suyo sería almarcenarlo en un array. Y una vez guardadas todas esas notas en el arreglo o array, ya realizas las operaciones pertinentes. Pienso que sería lo más sencillo.

Answer (score 1):

De la misma forma que tomaste las notas para un alumno usando `for`, podés repetir ese proceso 5 veces (para los alumnos):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);

        float notas;
        float notasTotal;
        float promedioGral;
        float suma = 0;
        float promedio;
        int a;
        int alumno;

        for(alumno = 0; alumno < 5; alumno++){


        for(a=1;a<=5;a++)

        {  
          System.out.println("ingresa la nota:"+a+"");
          notas=leer.nextFloat();
          suma=suma+notas;



        } 

        notasTotal = notasTotal + suma; //Para poder sacar el promedio 
                                          //de todos los alumnos
        promedio=suma/(a-1);
        System.out.println("el promedio de las notas es:"+promedio);


        if (promedio >= 5.0)
            System.out.println("El alumno esta aprobado:");

        else
            System.out.println("El alumno esta reprobado:");
    }

    suma = 0 //para limpiar esta variable y calcular el promedio del 
                 //siguiente alumno
    }
    // Para calcular el promedio general de todos los estudiantes:
    promedioGral = notasTotal/5;
    System.out.println("Promedio de todos los alumnos:" + promedioGral);
    }
```

Comment: de hecho ahi solo podria sacar el promedio general de todos los alumnos

Comment: Ahí agregué una recomendación para calcular el promedio de todos los estudiante. Gracias @srJJ!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo otro ejemplo en cual sumas y aun mantienes la informacion, por si requeires seguir usandola

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        float notas;
        float [][] matriz = new float[5][6]; 
        float sumaIndividual = 0;
        float promedio;
        int alumno;


        for(alumno = 1; alumno <= 5; alumno++)
        {  

          for(int s = 1; s <= 5; s++)
          {  
            System.out.println("ingresa la nota: "+s+" del estudiante: "+(alumno+1)+"");
            notas=leer.nextFloat();
            //rellenas la matriz con los datos
            matriz[alumno][s] = notas;
            //sumas a cada vuelta de ciclo interno los valores
            sumaIndividual = sumaIndividual + notas;
          }
          //en la casilla 6 almacenas la sumatoria para luego usarla
          matriz[alumno][6] = sumaIndividual;
          //reinicias la variable para el proximo ciclo
          sumaIndividual = 0;
        } 

      // ya teniendo toda la informacio la puede manupular mas facilmente 

        for(j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        {  
          //capturas el valor sumado y lo divides por el valor de 5
          float promedioIndividuo = matriz[j][6] / 5;

            if ( promedioIndividuo >= 5.0)
                System.out.println("El alumno esta aprobado:");

            else
                System.out.println("El alumno esta reprobado:");
            }
            //alamcenas cada valor
            promedio = promedio + promedioIndividuo;
        }

        System.out.println("El promedio de Todas las notas es: "+promedio);


    }
```

pruebalas, y mira cual se acopla a lo que necesitas, nos cuentas!

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que el problema lo tienes a la hora de guardar las **Notas**, ya que las guardas en una única variable. Lo suyo sería almacenarlo en un arreglo `double[] notas;`

```
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] notas = new double[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.print("Ingrese Nota: ");
    notas[i] = leer.nextDouble();   
}
```

Y después de tener todas las notas almacenadas, hacer las operaciones pertinentes..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Dejo el código al completo con los respectivos comentarios de cada operación. También sería bastante sencillo hacer todas estas operaciones con la **Stream API**, aunque esa ya es otra cuestión.

```
public class DatosOperaciones {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numNotas;
        double[] notas;
        double suma=0, promedio, max, min;
        int numAprobados=0, numSuspendidos=0;
        //---
        System.out.print("Numero de notas: ");
        numNotas = leer.nextInt();
        notas = new double[numNotas];

        System.out.println("Ingrese un total de: " + numNotas + " notas");
        for(int i=0; i<notas.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Nota "+ (i+1) + ": ");
            notas[i] = leer.nextDouble();
        }

        //Hacemos los calculos deseados..
        System.out.println("Las Notas a evaluar: ");
        for (double nota : notas) {
            System.out.print(nota + "   ");
        }

        //suma de las notas
        for (double nota : notas) {
            suma += nota;
        }
        System.out.println("\nSuma total de Notas: " + suma);

        //promedio de todas las notas
        promedio = suma / numNotas;
        System.out.println("El promedio es: " + promedio);

        //alumnos aprobados y suspendidos
        for (double nota : notas) {
            if(nota >= 5) {
                numAprobados++;
            } else {
                numSuspendidos++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Alumnos aprobados: " + numAprobados);
        System.out.println("Alumnos suspendidos: " + numSuspendidos);

        //nota mas alta
        max = notas[0];
        for (int i=0; i<notas.length; i++) {
            if(notas[i] > max){
                max = notas[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Nota mas alta: " + max);

        //nota mas baja
        min = notas[0];
        for (int i=0; i<notas.length; i++) {
            if(notas[i] < min){
                min = notas[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Nota mas baja: " + min);

    }
}
```

**Resultado del total de las operaciones:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2):

TODAS LS QUE PUSIERON SON DIFERENTES A LO QUE PIDEN, AQUI SE LAS DEJO Y LA PUEDEN SIMPLICAR SI GUSTAN

```
package Arreglos;
import java.util.Scanner;
     public class Calificaciones{
       public static void main(String [] args){
        int unidad1[], unidad2[], unidad3[], unidad4[], unidad5[];
        int num,i;
        int suma_unidad1, suma_unidad2, suma_unidad3, suma_unidad4, suma_unidad5;
        double media_alumno;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      //se crean los arreglos de enteros
        unidad1= new int [5];
        unidad2= new int[5];
        unidad3= new int[5];
        unidad4= new int[5];
        unidad5= new int[5];

        System.out.println("Sistema de calificaciones grupales de 5 alumnos");
       //se capturan las calif de la unidad 1.
        System.out.println("Notas de la primera unidad");
        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.print("Alumno " + (i+1)+" : ");
            unidad1[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
       //se capturan las calif de la unidad 2
        System.out.println("Notas de la segunda unidad");
        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.print("Alumno "+(i+1)+" : ");
            unidad2[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        //se capturan las calif de la unidad 3
        System.out.println("Notas de la tercera unidad");
        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.print("Alumno "+(i+1)+" : ");
            unidad3[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
       // se capturan las calif de la unidad 4
        System.out.println("Notas de la cuarta unidad");
        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.print("Alumno "+(i+1)+" : ");
            unidad4[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
       //se capturan los datos de la unidad 5
        System.out.println("Notas de la quinta unidad");
        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.print("Alumno "+(i+1)+" : ");
            unidad5[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        //calculamos las medias
        suma_unidad1 = 0;
        suma_unidad2 = 0;
        suma_unidad3 = 0;
        suma_unidad4 = 0;
        suma_unidad5 = 0;
        for (i =0; i < 5; i++){
            suma_unidad1 += unidad1[i];
            suma_unidad2 += unidad2[i];
            suma_unidad3 += unidad3[i];
            suma_unidad4 += unidad4[i];
            suma_unidad5 += unidad5[i];
        }
       //mostrar promedio
        System.out.println("Media unidad 1:"+ suma_unidad1/5);
        System.out.println("Media unidad 2:"+ suma_unidad2/5);
        System.out.println("Media unidad 3:"+ suma_unidad3/5);
        System.out.println("Media unidad 4:"+ suma_unidad4/5);
        System.out.println("Media unidad 5:"+ suma_unidad5/5);
        System.out.println();
     //se lee la posicion del alumno que nos interesa saber
     //de esa posicion se encuentra entre 0 y 3
        System.out.println("Introduce posicion del alumno (de 0 a 3: ");
        num=sc.nextInt();
     //la media del alumno es la suma de sus notas entre 5
        media_alumno = (double) 
      (unidad1[num]+unidad2[num]+unidad3[num]+unidad4[num]+unidad5[num])/5;
  
        System.out.println("La media del alumno es:"+ media_alumno);
        int grupal = 0;
        grupal = ((suma_unidad1 / 5) + (suma_unidad2 / 5) + (suma_unidad3 / 5) + 
    (suma_unidad4 / 5) + (suma_unidad5 / 5)) / 5;
        System.out.println("El promedio grupal es " + grupal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por tu contribución te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.