# Problema traduccion java

Tags: java, diccionarios, hashmap

Tengo que traducir este ejercicio que he hecho de python a java pero no consigo, trata de un programa que guarda los nombres y notas de unos alumnos y luego tengo que calcular la media de las notas. El programa pedirá el número de alumnos que vamos a introducir, pedirá su nombre e irá pidiendo sus notas hasta que introduzcamos un número negativo. Al final el programa nos mostrará la lista de alumnos y la nota media obtenida por cada uno de ellos.

Y el codigo de java me da error en la Arraylist, al crearla me dice que no admite parametros.
Codigo python:

```
alumnos = {}
cantidad = int(input("Introduce la cantidad de alumnos que vamos a guradar:"))
for num in range(cantidad):
    alumno = input("Nombre del alumno:")
while alumno in alumnos:
    print("Alumno ya existe.")
    alumno = input("Nombre del alumno:")
notas=[]
nota = int(input("Dame una nota del alumno (negativo para terminar):"))
while nota > 0:
    notas.append(nota)
    nota = int(input("Dame una nota del alumno (negativo para terminar):"))
alumnos[alumno] = notas.copy()

for alumno, notas in alumnos.items():
    print("%s ha sacado de nota media %f" % (alumno,sum(notas)/len(notas)))
```

Y este es mi codigo de java que solo falta hacer la media de todas las notas:

```
        System.out.println("Ejercicio 4");
        HashMap<String, ArrayList> d4 = new HashMap();
        Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("¿que cantidad de alumnos quieres guardar?");
        Integer cant = sc4.nextInt();
        sc4.nextLine();
        for(int num = 0; num < cant; num++){
            System.out.println("Nombre de dicho alumno");
            String alumno = sc4.nextLine();
        while(d4.containsKey(alumno)){
            System.out.println("El alumno ya existe.");
            System.out.println("Nombre de dicho alumno");
            alumno = sc4.nextLine();
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> notas = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Escribe la nota (se acaba si le pones una nota negativa):");
        Integer nota = sc4.nextInt();
        sc4.nextLine();
        while(nota > 0){ notas.add(nota);
        System.out.println("Escribe la nota (se acaba si le pones una nota negativa):");
        nota = sc4.nextInt();
        sc4.nextLine();
        }
        d4.put(alumno, notas);
        }
        System.out.println(d4);
```

Me da el siguiente error:
[image: Error]

Comment: Hola. Tienes una respuesta ya publicada hace un tiempo que quizás te puede ayudar.

[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195852/como-podr%C3%ADa-ingresar-5-notas-de-5-alumnos-y-sacar-promedio-solo-pude-hacerlo-c)

Comment: El código de Python que te dieron, ¿está correcto? Veo que hay muchos errores en la ideación y que si tratas de traducir eso directamente simplemente no va a funcionar. El ciclo while, esta fuera del ciclo for en python.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy suponiendo que tu error está en que a veces el scanner toma el input como la última línea que hayas mostrado en consola. Esto sucede generalmente cuando cambias de tipo de dato que estas esperando en el scanner. Y por lo tanto, en algún punto tienes un dato que no corresponde al esperado.

En mi solución, antes de introducir nombres de alumnos, doy un extra nextLine() para que Java no tome algo que haya impreso como el valor leído por el scanner.

Segundo, no entiendo la necesidad de un ArrayList para las notas. Es memoria extra y realmente no te están pidiendo conocer el listado de notas, solo el promedio. Además puedes reducir el uso de while y for anidaos a solo dos.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, Double> alumnosNotas = new HashMap();

    System.out.println("Introduce el número de alumnos: ");
    int numeroDeAlumnos = sc.nextInt();
    while(alumnosNotas.size() < numeroDeAlumnos) {
        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumno: ");
        sc.nextLine();
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        if (alumnosNotas.containsKey(nombre)) {
            System.out.println("El alumno ya existe");
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println("Introduce la nota de " + nombre + ": ");
        int nota = sc.nextInt();
        double sumaNotas = 0;
        int numeroDeNotas = 0;
        while(nota > -1) {
            sumaNotas += nota;
            ++numeroDeNotas;
            System.out.println("Introduce la nota de " + nombre + ": ");
            nota = sc.nextInt();
        }

        alumnosNotas.put(nombre, sumaNotas / numeroDeNotas);
    }

    for (String s : alumnosNotas.keySet())
        System.out.println(s + " : " + alumnosNotas.get(s));
  }
}
```

Puedes probar el código en el siguiente replit: https://replit.com/@JacoboTapia/StudentsAverage#Main.java